# How to get random color variation on a single mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

I am trying to get color variation and to bake it in a single mesh but the Object Info Random only works if i separate the meshes. Is there an alternative way to get the same result with the meshes combined, they aren't attached between them.

[image]

Comment: I don't know of any way to currently do this in Cycles, though I would also like to know if anyone has figured out any way to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Following the several comments, I've thought an addon can be useful to do that and may have a general interest.

[image]

What does it do:

- Identify loose parts of the object (or all selected objects)
- Generate a random color for each loose part
- Follow the mesh loops to assign the vertex colors

(can be installed as an addon)

The code is commented below (please comment if needed):

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Assign random vertex color to each loose part of a mesh",
    "author": "lemon",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "Properties Editor > Object data",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh"}

import bpy
import time
import random
from mathutils import Color

def LoosePartsMakeVertPaths( verts, edges ):
    #Initialize the path with all vertices indexes
    result = {v.index: set() for v in verts}
    #Add the possible paths via edges
    for e in edges:
        result[e.vertices[0]].add(e.vertices[1])
        result[e.vertices[1]].add(e.vertices[0])
    return result

def LoosePartsFollowEdges( startingIndex, paths ):
    current = [startingIndex]
    result = set( current )

    follow = True
    while follow:
        #Get indexes that are still in the paths
        eligible = set( [ind for ind in current if ind in paths] )
        if len( eligible ) == 0:
            follow = False #Stops is no more
        else:
            #Get the corresponding links
            next = [paths.pop( i ) for i in eligible]
            #Get the new links as new inputs
            current = set( [ind for sub in next for ind in sub] )
            result = result.union( current )

    return result

def LoosePartsCountIslands( obj ):
    #Prepare the paths/links from each vertex to others
    paths = LoosePartsMakeVertPaths( obj.data.vertices, obj.data.edges )
    found = True
    n = 0
    while found:
        try:
            #Get one input as long there is one
            startingIndex = next( iter( paths.keys() ) )
            n = n + 1
            #Deplete the paths dictionary following this starting index
            LoosePartsFollowEdges( startingIndex, paths )               
        except:
            found = False
    return n

def LoosePartGetIslands( obj ):
    paths = LoosePartsMakeVertPaths( obj.data.vertices, obj.data.edges )

    result = []

    found = True
    while found:
        try:
            #Get one input as long there is one
            startingIndex = next( iter( paths.keys() ) )
            #Deplete the paths dictionary following this starting index and append the result
            result.append( LoosePartsFollowEdges( startingIndex, paths ) )
        except:
            found = False

    return result

def RandomColor( rnd ):
    return Color( (rnd.random(), rnd.random(), rnd.random()) )

def RandomColors( rnd, count ):
    return [RandomColor( rnd ) for i in range( count )]

def ColorFromVertexIndex( vertexIndex, looseParts, colors ):
    for c, lp in zip( colors, looseParts ):
        if vertexIndex in lp:
            return c
    return Color()

def RandomVertexColorsByLooseParts( obj, vcolName, useSeed, seed ):

    rnd = random.Random()
    if useSeed:
        rnd.seed( seed )

    mesh = obj.data

    #Create vertex colors if it does not already exist    
    if vcolName not in mesh.vertex_colors:
        mesh.vertex_colors.new( vcolName )
    #Update it so that it is available below
    mesh.vertex_colors.update()
    #Get the vertex colors
    vertexColors = mesh.vertex_colors[vcolName]

    #Get loose parts
    looseParts = LoosePartGetIslands( obj )
    #Generate random colors
    colors = RandomColors( rnd, len(looseParts) )

    mesh.loops.update()

    #Follow the loops    
    for i, vertexIndex in enumerate( [loop.vertex_index for loop in mesh.loops] ):
        #Assign vertex colors from loop index and vertex index
        vertexColors.data[i].color = ColorFromVertexIndex( vertexIndex, looseParts, colors )

def InitProperties():
    bpy.types.Scene.VertexColorsName = bpy.props.StringProperty( name = "Vertex colors", description = "Vertex colors to use or create", default = "Col" )
    bpy.types.Scene.VertexColorsUseSeed = bpy.props.BoolProperty( name = "Use seed", description = "Use fixed seed to generate random values" ) 
    bpy.types.Scene.VertexColorsSeed = bpy.props.IntProperty( name = "Seed", description = "Seed for random values" ) 
    bpy.types.Scene.VertexColorsAllSelected = bpy.props.BoolProperty( name = "All selected objects", description = "Apply to all selected object or only active one" ) 

class RndVColToLoosePartsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Random vcol to loose parts"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES";
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW";
    bl_context = ""

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return context.object and context.scene

    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = context.scene

        layout.prop( scn, 'VertexColorsName', icon='GROUP_VCOL' )
        layout.prop( scn, 'VertexColorsUseSeed' )
        layout.prop( scn, 'VertexColorsSeed' )
        layout.operator( "rndvcoltolooseparts.ope")
        layout.prop( scn, 'VertexColorsAllSelected' )

class RndVColToLooseParts(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname="rndvcoltolooseparts.ope"
    bl_label="Generate random vcol to each loose parts"

    def execute(self, context):

        scene = context.scene
        obj = context.object

        if scene and obj and obj.type == 'MESH':

            prevMode = obj.mode
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode='OBJECT', toggle=False )

            if scene.VertexColorsAllSelected:
                for obj in [obj for obj in context.selected_objects if obj.type == 'MESH']:
                    RandomVertexColorsByLooseParts( obj, scene.VertexColorsName, scene.VertexColorsUseSeed, scene.VertexColorsSeed )
            else:
                RandomVertexColorsByLooseParts( obj, scene.VertexColorsName, scene.VertexColorsUseSeed, scene.VertexColorsSeed )

            bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode=prevMode, toggle=False )

        return {'FINISHED'}     


def register():
    InitProperties()
    bpy.utils.register_class(RndVColToLooseParts)
    bpy.utils.register_class(RndVColToLoosePartsPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RndVColToLooseParts)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RndVColToLoosePartsPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**2.80 Version.**

[image]

- Creates a random grey-scale color and assigns to vertex color for each
  mesh loose part.  Each component of the rgba vector is the same. Can be plugged into factor sockets individually.
- Sets the face material color of each part to the active material
  index. [image]
  *Example material used in image above, for the greyscale plug the color attribute node directly into shader.*

Addon script.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Mesh Islands Random Vertex Color",
    "author": "batFINGER",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "F3 Search",
    "description": "Assign random greyscale vertex color to mesh islands",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh"}

import bpy
import bmesh
from random import random
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty
from mathutils import Vector


def walk_island(vert):
    ''' walk all un-tagged linked verts '''
    vert.tag = True
    yield (vert)
    linked_verts = [
        e.other_vert(vert) for e in vert.link_edges
        if not e.other_vert(vert).tag
    ]
    for v in linked_verts:
        if v.tag:
            continue
        yield from walk_island(v)


def get_islands(bm, verts=[]):
    def tag(verts, switch):
        for v in verts:
            v.tag = switch

    tag(bm.verts, True)
    tag(verts, False)
    ret = {"islands": []}
    verts = set(verts)
    while verts:
        v = verts.pop()
        verts.add(v)
        island = set(walk_island(v))
        faces = set(
            f for x in island for f in x.link_faces
            if all(v.tag for v in f.verts))
        edges = set(
            e for x in island for e in x.link_edges
            if all(v.tag for v in e.verts))
        ret["islands"].append(island.union(edges).union(faces))
        tag(island, False)  # remove tag = True
        verts -= island
    return ret


class BMIslands(list):
    def __init__(self, bm):
        self.extend(BMeshIsland(i, island) for i, island in enumerate(get_islands(bm, verts=bm.verts)["islands"]))
        self.sort(key=lambda i: (i.co.x, i.co.y))
        for i, island in enumerate(self):
            island.index = i


class BMeshIsland:
    def __init__(self, index, geom):
        self.index = index
        self.verts = [e for e in geom if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
        self.co = sum([v.co for v in self.verts], Vector()) / len(self.verts)
        self.faces = [e for e in geom if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMFace)]


class MESH_OT_random_island_vertex_color(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.random_island_vert_color"
    bl_label = "Random Island Vert Color"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    islands = None
    bm = None

    refresh: BoolProperty(name="Refresh")
    color_map: StringProperty(
        name="Color Map", default="vertcol")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return(context.object
               and context.object.mode == 'OBJECT'
               and context.object.type == 'MESH')

    def main(self, ob):
        me = ob.data

        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(me)
        self.bm = bm

        self.islands = BMIslands(bm)

    def randomize(self, ob):
        me = ob.data
        clayers = self.bm.loops.layers.color
        color_layer = clayers.get(self.color_map) or clayers.new(self.color_map)

        ami = ob.active_material_index
        for island in self.islands:
            r = random()
            for f in island.faces:
                f.material_index = ami
                for l in f.loops:
                    #l[color_layer] = (r, r, r, 1)
                    l[color_layer] = (r, ) * 4

        self.bm.to_mesh(me)
        me.update()

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        ob = context.object
        self.main(ob)
        return self.execute(context)

    def execute(self, context):
        self.randomize(context.object)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self, "color_map")

        row.prop(self, "refresh", text="", icon='FILE_REFRESH')
        layout.operator(self.__class__.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_random_island_vertex_color)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MESH_OT_random_island_vertex_color)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Great! Many thanks for your bmesh magic. Had to find an automatic workflow to bake id maps based on random vertex colors per island in painter. Created a hsv version based on your code which allows to set the colors in vertex paint mode as well: https://gist.github.com/p2or/ab314836285579cdfdb5d7848af8ee5c Also fixed a bug when assigning a new name if there is more than one layer present. Anyway, this script is super quick and pretty useful. Can we have a repo for this?

Comment: @p2or Cheers. Update looks good. Thanks for the support.  [Not too many too quickly, lol (based on time matching comment above)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger?tab=reputation)

Answer (score 6):

In Blender 2.8, there is an attribute "Random Per Island" in the geometry input. It only works with Cycles though (not Eevee nor the material preview). It does the job!
[image: screenshot of geometry input node]

Comment: nasty..this was the easiest and worked like a charm..THANK YOU

Answer (score 4):

You may use a ***Color Ramp*** node to do it. Add a ***Separate XYZ*** node (*Add*-->*Converter*-->*SeparateXYZ*) and plug its *Z output* to the *Fac input* of the *ColorRamp* node. Set its interpolation type to *Constant*. Use ***'+'*** sign to add colors and set the sliders to fit the mesh's segments.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The problem is that it wont give a good result if i combine multiple assets with different shapes.

Comment: You could use vertex colors to flag different regions, instead of using locations within the generated coords box.

Comment: @JtheNinja Sounds good! Please write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pure Blender GUI way:

1. Add a new shape key (basis) and then another, call it 'merged'. Set merged to value 1.
2. Change pivot point to individual origins. Select all verts.
3. <kbd>S</kbd>,  <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  All loose parts are merged into a single point in space.
4. Unwrap the mesh, sphere projection. each of these loose parts has all vertices in a tiny tiny area in uv space.
5. disable the shape key merged, or set to 0, or delete.
6. I can post a node setup, but you probably get it. By using a procedural texture in uv space, you get that loose part randomness you wanted.