# How to batch modify the vertex colors of different meshes

Tags: vertex-groups, vertex-colors

I hope to use different vertex coloring to create the effect of edge lines. Different vertex groups can achieve this effect by giving different colors. But currently I have a large number of meshes that need to be modified. How do I batch mesh vertex groups? Grouping, or how to modify the vertex color of the mesh in batches?
thank you all
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Script for Inset faces.**

[image]
*Very basic test run on inset cube*

Using same concept as [How to get random color variation on a single mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76520/how-to-get-random-color-variation-on-a-single-mesh)

- By looking at screen shot it appears the models all have inset faces.
- Assuming this is the case then

  - For each unique mesh of selected objects
  - Get or create a color layer from setting for `layer_color_name` Blender uses the default of "Col"
  - Sort faces by area
  - Set loop verts colors to `inset_color` on "inset face" (largest)
  - Find all the faces connected by edge to this face and set to `edge_color`
  - Repeat until all faces processed

Test script, fill in the name of color layer, and the two colors.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context

# parameters

color_layer_name = "Col"
inset_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
edge_color = (0, 0, 0, 1)


meshes = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH')
bm = bmesh.new()

for me in meshes:
    clayers = bm.loops.layers.color
    color_layer = clayers.get(color_layer_name) or clayers.new(color_layer_name)
    bm.from_mesh(me)
    faces = sorted(bm.faces[:], key=lambda f: f.calc_area())
    while faces:
        
        # big face is an inset
        def color(face, color, material_index):
            face.material_index = material_index
            for l in face.loops:
                l[color_layer] = color
        face = faces.pop()
        color(face, inset_color, 0)
        insets = set(
            f for e in face.edges
            for f in e.link_faces
            ) - {face}
        for f in insets:
            color(f, edge_color, 1)
            if f in faces:
                faces.remove(f)
        bm.to_mesh(me)
        me.update() # see result
    bm.clear()
```

**To run the script.**

Copy the script and paste into text editor. Click the run script "play" button.  Didn't make much effort to optimize for speed, for all objects may take a minute or two. Wait for the button to return to unpressed state. While it is running blender will be unresponsive.

Result of running over all objects test file.

[image]

Many of the objects have no material assigned, but the vertex colors have been set. Some use material slot 1.

Here is a fix script to ensure all objects have two materials

```
import bpy

mat = bpy.data.materials[0]

for me in bpy.data.meshes:
    while len(me.materials) < 2:
        me.materials.append(None)
    me.materials[1] = me.materials[0] = mat
```

Have edited original code to assign material index  0 to insets, and 1 to edges. (These really could use same material since it is using vert color)

Now after having run this to ensure that each mesh has two materials

[image]

Some objects are not a result of all inset faces so may not have desired result.  Other methods to look at would be looking for "skinny" faces.

**Color Gradient.**

To get a gradient on the "ridge"

- Look for all verts that are only linked to edge faces. (Using the face material_index set in fix script above
- Set every loop vert color of the corresponding vert to `ridge_color`

Run this after running scripts above at least once.

[image]

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
import bmesh

context = bpy.context

color_layer_name = "Col"
ridge_color = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)


meshes = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH')
bm = bmesh.new()

for me in meshes:
    loops = len(me.loops)

    color_layer = (me.vertex_colors.get(color_layer_name)
                   or me.vertex_colors.new(name=color_layer_name)
                   )
    loop_colors = np.empty(4 * loops)
    loop_verts = np.ones(loops)
    me.loops.foreach_get(
            "vertex_index",
            loop_verts,
            )
            
    color_layer.data.foreach_get(
            "color",
            loop_colors,
            )
    loop_colors = loop_colors.reshape(-1, 4)       
    bm.from_mesh(me)
    verts = [
            v.index for v in bm.verts 
            if all(f.material_index == 1 for f in v.link_faces)
            ]
    bm.clear()
    indices = np.where(np.in1d(loop_verts, verts))[0]

    loop_colors[indices] = ridge_color

    color_layer.data.foreach_set(
            "color",
            loop_colors.ravel(),
            )
    me.update()
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much, but I am not very proficient in code and cannot operate successfully,I re-uploaded the file, thank you very much

Comment: Paste script into text editor. In OBJECT mode select any or all of the mesh objects to color, then click the run script "play" button.

Comment: Great. I succeeded, but currently only one mesh can be modified. How to generate it in batches?

Comment: Had to make a small edit since all meshes aren't the result of indiv inset faces. It will modify all the meshes of selected objects. Ran succesfully on all. BUT you have not assigned a material to many of them, and hence they have no visible result. _btw_ have you looked at using  freestyle  to marking and rendering  edge lines without adding geometry?

Comment: Added a fix it script to give each object at least 2 materials, and a GIF demo of usage.

Comment: I made it! thank you so much! I have another question. The vertex color I manually changed has a gradient effect between the two colors. Can this effect be achieved?

Comment: I do this because I need to import the vertex color content into the shader written by godot

Comment: NP, "just checking"  thought it worth asking 8*).  Re gradient query consider asking a new question.

Comment: All right, thank you very much, and have a nice day～

Comment: Added an edit to give different color to "ridge".

Comment: It's a success! Thank you again sincerely

Comment: @chunzhong If so, please consider to accept the answer, thanks. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour, also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers