# Random Color to 1 Object

Tags: python, color, color-management, text-editor

I have one wall in the project I am working on. I want the color of this wall to change when I run the code. I did research but couldn't find it.

```
import random

rgb = ()
for i in range(3) :
    rgb += ((random.randrange(1, 10, 3) /10),)

mat.diffuse_color = rgb
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get random color variation on a single mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76520/how-to-get-random-color-variation-on-a-single-mesh)

Comment: Not exactly, I want the selected object to change, so the duplicated objects change.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add all relevant details to understand your goal? Hard to guess what you want based on the provided code, you're just assigning *something* to the viewport's material color. Do you would like to change the viewport material color or the base color of the shader? "Radom Color to 1 Object" suggests (to me) that you'd like to randomize the color of one object or mesh (hence the link to the other question, principles are the same). Can you provide a minified blend file or at least a screenshot to see your geometry and what kind of dupes you have?

Comment: It's fairly easy to generate a random color.  The question I have is what do you want to use to trigger the random color to change.  In python it might be a button on a panel or a custom property that you change, or even something driven by the frame number of an animation.